# Is there a certbot command to display account details?

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

Is there a way to display the certbot account details (e.g. account ID, registered email, etc.)

I'm aware I can update the registration (including email) with `certbot register --update-registration --email <email>`; and that the account ID can be seen in the URI of regr.json under `/etc/letsencrypt/accounts/acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory/`.

But just wondering whether there's a command to display all the account related information…

Answer (score 4):

Since version [1.23](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/releases/tag/v1.23.0) there is a new subcommand to show details:

```
certbot show_account
```